# Average time between timestamps per group not in order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the `mean` time between timestamps per group. However, the groups are not ordered.

Code to create df:

```
d = {'ID': ['AI100', 'AI200', 'AI200', 'AI100','AI200','AI100'],
     'Date': ['2019-01-10', '2018-06-01', '2018-06-11','2019-01-15','2018-06-21', '2019-01-22']}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
data = data[['ID', 'Date']]
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data  

    ID  Date
0   AI100   2019-01-10
1   AI200   2018-06-01
2   AI200   2018-06-11
3   AI100   2019-01-15
4   AI200   2018-06-21
5   AI100   2019-01-22
```

I tried the following:

```
data = data.sort_values(['ID','Date'],ascending=True).groupby('ID').head(3) #group the IDs
data['diffs'] = data['Date'].diff()
data['diffs'] = data['diffs'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
data = data.groupby(['ID'])[('diffs')].agg('mean')
```

However, this yields:

```
data.add_suffix('ID').reset_index()

    ID  diffs
0   AI100ID 6.000000
1   AI200ID -71.666667
```

The mean time for group `AI100ID` is correct,  but not for group `AI200ID`.

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue you're having here is that you aren't calculating your diffs by the group so it's calculating the difference between the previous group's last value and the new group's first value.

Change your line to this and you should get the expected result:

```
data['diffs'] = data.groupby('ID')['Date'].diff()
```

**Footnote:**

Another other tip unrelated to the main problem, but just in case you were unaware:

```
data['diffs'] = data['diffs'].apply(lambda x: x.days)
```

Can be written to use faster vectorised operations using the `.dt` accessor:

```
data['diffs'] = data['diffs'].dt.days
```